# Tmp detached view should be removed from RecyclerView before it can be recycled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recyclerview and it updates everytime I make a successful network call. Interestingly, I am getting this random crash with this message

```
Tmp detached view should be removed from RecyclerView before it can be recycled: ViewHolder{6d86a51 position=1 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 update tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{9ca4cde VFED..... ......ID 0,145-1080,387 #7f0a0194 app:id/recycler_view aid=1073742248}
```

I tried removing animationlayoutchange but still randomly happening this.

any idea or suggestions?

Comment: i think its similar. I tried with the solutions without recyclerView.itemAnimator = null.. still its happening randomly.